# Drupal Views Warning

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I get this warning every time I update a view:

> Notice: Undefined index: revision table en field_views_field_default_views_data()
>   (línea 182 de path_to_modules/field.views.inc)

Does anyone else get the same warning?

Comment: If you are seeing errors with a module, check out the issue queue: http://drupal.org/project/issues/views.  If you don't see others with the same problem, try creating an issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to the developer views module 7.x-3.x-dev to remove the error. The error is bound in 7.x-3.3 and has been removed in the developer version.

Comment: Indeed the problem was solve when I updated the views module version . Thanks